# Imported svn repo, not getting pushed to github

Tags: github, git-svn

I imported an existing svn-repo into my preset git repo using the `git svn clone http://svn/repo/here/trunk` command. Now I can see all the logs of the svn commits done after firing the `git log` command.

I want to push these files to github, but `git add` and `git commit` do not show any files for the same.

So which command will add and commit these files to the remote git repo?

Answer (score 0):

`git svn` already added and committed those files to your local repo.

Make sure git is configured with the right username and email (ie the ones of your GitHub repo):

```
git config --global user.name "Name"
git config --global user.email email@gmail.com
```

You need to add a remote to your GitHub repo and push.

```
cd /path/to/your/local/repo
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/username/reponame
git push --all
git push --tags
```

Note that when you create a brand new repo on GitHub, it might comes with already one commit (with one file, the `README.md`).
In that case, the `git push` from your local repo might be rejected, because the history of your repo isn't based on that one commit of your GitHub repo.

If that is the case (failed `git push`), then:

```
cd /path/to/your/local/repo
git remote add origin https://username@github.com/username/reponame
git pull origin master
git push --all
git push --tags
```

Comment: The `git remote add` command is giving me this message `fatal: remote origin already exists.`. Tried the sequence of commands but nothing was added to the remote repo.

Comment: @eminemence then try `git remote set-url` (I have changed the answer)

Comment: Thanks for the answers till now. `git remote` worked fine this time. But both the `git push`'s returned `Everything up-to-date`. Never thought svn to git migration would be such a headache. Just to add, I have tried running the svn2git tool, but as I am on windows, it's not running fine. Hence I took up the tasks of manually importing svn to git.

Comment: @eminemence then might I recommend subgit? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19156792/6309 But make sure first your GitHub repo doesn't already contain the svn repo history.

Comment: none of the above methods have worked. I am not marking this as an answer in the hope of some solution.

Comment: @eminemence I would still recommend subgit.